# Online service for buffering rss feed items

Tags: rss, buffer, feed

I am desperately looking for an online service for buffering rss feed items. 
Basically, I have one rss feed that publishes approximately 40 items per hours; however the rss feed only exposes the latest 20. I would like to have access to a buffered rss feed that would for example expose the latest 250 items.
If such a service exists, and you know about it, let me know!
Ben.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just consume the service and write it to DB?  Then you have access as far back as you care to go.  This is simple in just about every scripting language out there.  And, as a bonus, it'll lessen the amount of http hits your site does (if you're displaying to the user from DB instead of on load from the RSS feed site)

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://superfeedr.com (I'm the founder). We do not "cache" the feeds, but we poll them often enough that we should not miss any entry.
Also, check [this CouchApp](http://github.com/maxogden/couchpubtato), as it can allow you to very easily store these updates in a couchdb app. You can be running in a few minutes, without even needing a server.